# Rails column association with integer array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, pg

I have 2 models, `User` and `Email`, As it's clear a user will have an email, as `sender` and `recipient`.

In `User` model

```
  has_many :sent_emails, class_name: "Email", foreign_key: "sender_id"
  has_many :received_emails, class_name: "Email", foreign_key: "recipient_id"
```

and in `Email` model

```
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User", primary_key: "id"
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User", primary_key: "id"
```

That's how am getting associations, That's was for information only, The problem is: I have other 2 columns as `cc` and `bcc` as

```
add_column :emails, :cc, :integer, default: [], array: true
add_column :emails, :bcc, :integer, default: [], array: true
```

I want to make associations between email and user on those columns as well.

So That if I add,

```
 => #<Email id: nil, sender_id: 5, recipient_id: 10, body: "Hello its first email.", subject: "Hello Hello", state: 1, head: nil, tail: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, cc: [9, 8], bcc: [4,19]>
```

As I can do `Email.first.sender` or `Email.first.recipient` I can get the user, So that I may do `Email.first.cc` or `Email.first.bcc` I can get the users.

As I can do `User.first.sent_emails` and `User.first.received_emails`, I can get `User.first.cc_mails` or `User.first.bcc_mails`?

Is that possible to build association like that?

Comment: why not just a one to many table, but using pg array?

Comment: How? i have no idea how to do that?

Comment: Actually there are going to be many CC or BCC to one email,

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Rails does not support `has_many` relation for this kind of structure. But you can make manual methods `cc_emails` and `bcc_emails`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def cc_mails
    Email.where("? = ANY (cc)", id)
  end

  def bcc_mails
    Email.where("? = ANY (bcc)", id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The more idiomatic rails way to build this sort of relationship to use the `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has_many :through` association:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

This will use a pivot table instead of an integer array in the database.  The documentation (linked to above) describes how to create the database schema for this.

You can then define the association on your user model something like:

`has_many :ccs
has_many :ccd_emails, through: :ccs`

Using this schema and these associations, ActiveRecord will give you the functions you want built in, including `User#ccd_emails` and `User#ccd_email_ids` which will give you array-like representations of User instances or integers ids respectively.

This also has the advantage that it is 100% portable to different databases.